# How to parallelize a nested for loop to actually make it faster?

Tags: python, concurrency

I am processing an image and I have its pixels in an array of size 1920x1200 (can differ based on the image). I am iterating through every pixel and increasing some global variables based on different conditions. So I basically now have a nested for loop that I use to iterate through pixels.

```py
variable1 = 0  #variables declared globally
variable2 = 0

# this method gets a pixel and increases some global variables if the conditions are met
def mapp(pixel):
    global variable1
    global variable2

    if(condition):
        variable1 = variable1 + 1
        return
    if(condition2):
        variable2 = variable2 + 1
        return
```

```py
# im.size[0] is one dimension of the image and im.size[1] is another dimension.
# pix[w,h] is used to access a pixel at coordinates (w,h)

for w in range(0,im.size[0]):
    for h in range(0,im.size[1]):
        mapp(pix[w,h])


#after finishing the iterations I print those variables
```

I want to make it concurrent so that **X** processes would run at the same time with each process only processing **1/X** of the image, making the program run faster. How would I do that?

---

Is it a good practice to have global variables and have them be possibly increased with each iteration when trying to make a program concurrent or are there any better approaches? If so, what are those approches and how do I do it? Is there anything that could go wrong in this situation?  (I am quite new to Python and concurrency overall)

Comment: This question is very broad. Take a look at some resources, and come back with more specific questions. Take a look at Python Multiprocessing and Multithreading.

Comment: also, parallelizing code should not be used as a silver bullet, you should first look at the ability to optimize code further. In this case, it seems like you really should be looking at vectorization first, instead of iteration along the pixels one by one.

Comment: I do not think it's that broad. Generally I just want to parallelize a nested for loop. I just gave some context for people to have a better understanding of what I am doing  so that they could understand what approach is best :) The reason why I want parallelization, not some other method of speeding things up is because it is for a project that is all about parallelization. The aim of this is to see that it takes a lot of time to iterate through every pixel and it should take less when parallelized

Comment: Parallelizing the processing of the individual pixels of an image in pure Python is not something that can be expected to make it faster, regardless of whether you use multithreading or multiprocessing.

Comment: I've read that multithreading does not actually speed things up because of Global Interpreter Lock. But why wouldn't multiprocessing be able do it? As I've read, it does offer some increase in speed. Is there no way it can be done? Can't the array be split into, let's say 4 parts, so that 4 cores would be able to process it? @martineau Sorry if it seems lika a trivial question to You, just want to fully understand it.

Comment: Multiprocessing avoids the GIL issue, but it involves a _lot_ of overhead especially if data needs to be shared between the processes…so using it is very unlikely to result in something that runs faster in this per-pixel scenario.

Comment: Is it just relevant to Python? So is there no way in Python to make use of concurrency in this scenario? Even to make it at least a bit faster? I am not expecting a 2x or 3x increase in speed, but at least something. @martineau

Comment: Yes, it's mostly a limitation imposed by the Python interpreter's implementation. You might be able to get some improvement by not having per-pixel tasks. For example, you could split the image into two or more sections and process each of those in separate independent processes (and presumably gather-together the results after they've all finished—which unfortunately will also introduce overhead).

Comment: The thing that I'm doing is checking the color of every pixel and after it's all done outputting the percentages of the colors the image has. So I kind of have to go pixel by pixel.

Comment: I'd start by looking at using `numpy` and how to vectorize things, then maybe also look at Cython.  you should be able to get things 100x faster using these relatively easily.  knowing what your `condition` and `condition2` are would help make more specific suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are costs associated with parallelism and different types of parallelism. As suggested in the comments, I would take a look at Multi-Processing and Multi-Threading. A primary difference between the two is that threading is subject to the GIL (Global-Interpreter-Lock) when multiprocessing is not.

As far as global variables go, it is generally better to use local variables as access to them is faster but globals do have their place in programming. In your case I would not use global variables. Instead you can use local variable and perform something like a reduction.

On the parallel side, A simple solution to your problem is to use a pool from multiprocessing but beware that there is overhead with this option.

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np

variable1 = 0
variable2 = 0

def mapp(pixel):
    if(pixel==1):
        return 0
    if(pixel==2):
        return 1

if __name__ == "__main__":

    X = 4 #number of processes
    #Example array
    exampleShape = (10,10)
    exampleArray = np.ones(exampleShape)
    reshapedArray = np.reshape(exampleArray,exampleShape[0]*exampleShape[1])
    for i in range(0,len(reshapedArray),3):
        reshapedArray[i] = 2
    #create pool
    myPool = mp.Pool(X)
    res = myPool.map(mapp,reshapedArray)
    #Reduction
    resSum = sum(res)
    variable1 += resSum
    variable2 += abs(len(res)-resSum)
    #close pool
    myPool.close()
```